# How do I get the next cell in a series based on the information in another cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, sequence

I have a list needing to be updated frequently that I'm trying to automate to make it a quicker process to update said list. In one column I have the full list of each possible value. In another column, I have one of those values entered in manually. I have one more column that I need to be the next sequentially from the master column that has each possible value.

Let's say in column A I have, starting from A2:
"Alpha, Beta, Charlie, etc."
Then in column B, I've entered one of those entries found in column A:
B2 = Delta, B3 = Alpha, B4 = Alpha, B5 = Charlie
In column C, I want each cell to read the info in column B and find the next term in the sequence:
C2 = Epsilon, C3 = Bravo, C4 = Bravo, C5 = Delta

Is there any way to do this in Google Sheets?

I've tried to find any kind of formula that might work to get this to work, with mixed results. The closest I've gotten is using OFFSET to get the next cell from the series in column A, but that doesn't read any of the data entered in column B.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this in **Cell_C2**:*

```js
=index(A:A,xmatch(B2,A:A)+1)
```